# How to measure client side performance?

Tags: web-application

We have a new web page being developed and it loads slower then the other pages by a second or two.

I'm trying to determine when a page is loading too slow for our clients.

The time it takes a page to load will also change depending on what machine it is running on, what other resources are being used, etc...

Is the threshold for 'This page is taking too long to load' based on opinions? At what point can we push back and say this page is taking too long to load, please fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools that create a metric for Website performance, for example https://tools.pingdom.com/. Regarding the question if "Too long" is based on opinions, I'd say too long is every time that can be reduced.

You could check if packages are aggregated as far as possible (Sure, aggregating all resources doesn't really change the amount of data transferred but every single call creates avoidable overhead), if every resource is minimized and gets delivered gziped and of course if expire dates make sense so the browser can effectively cache them. There are incredible amounts of checks that you could run to make sure that your pages become as fast as possible, which of those are feasible for your application is another question though.